# How to allocate more storage for Android Studio Emulator on mac?

Tags: android-emulator, storage, space

I am using Android Studio Emulator to play games on my Macmini. I have been searching for how to allocate more storage space for the Android Emulator. Like the attached screenshot, it says "Total used of 16.00 GB." It seems the 16.00GB is set by the system. How can I increase it to more than 16.00 GB? There is more storage space on my Macmini.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To increase the storage space for the Android Emulator on your Mac mini, you can follow these steps:

1. Open Android Studio.
2. Go to Device Manager.
3. Click the Edit Icon to edit the AVD (Android Virtual Device).
4. Click on Show Advanced settings.
5. Change the Internal Storage to your desired value.
6. Click Finish.
7. Confirm the popup by clicking yes.

you might need to Wipe Data on the AVD and confirm the popup by clicking yes. This will erase all data on the emulator, so back up any important data before proceeding.

Remember, these steps will only increase the storage allocated to the Android Emulator, not the actual storage on your Mac mini. If you’re running out of space on your Mac mini, you might need to free up some space or consider upgrading your hardware. I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but this is not the answer I'm looking for. I know how to change internal storage but this won't solve my problem. And I need to keep my game so I can't wipe data. As my question is asking, just how to allocate more actual storage from my macmini to the android studio emulator. Fo example, increase from 16.00 GB to 50 GB.